# Running Steam and Dota 2 with primus

Tags: steam, bumblebee, primus

I wished to run my steam with bumblebee but faced a problem: when I try to run steam using primusrun, I get segfault. Anything else also doesn't run with primus. Here's an example of running `primusrun glxspheres64` with `LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose`.

```
shy@shy-Inspiron-N5110:~$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose primusrun glxspheres64
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI3 capable
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: driver does not expose __driDriverGetExtensions_swrast(): /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so: undefined symbol: __driDriverGetExtensions_swrast
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/shy/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/shy/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Polygons in scene: 62464
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI3 capable
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: driver does not expose __driDriverGetExtensions_swrast(): /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so: undefined symbol: __driDriverGetExtensions_swrast
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/shy/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/shy/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Visual ID of window: 0x5f
Context is Direct
OpenGL Renderer: GeForce GT 525M/PCIe/SSE2
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI3 capable
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: driver does not expose __driDriverGetExtensions_swrast(): /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so: undefined symbol: __driDriverGetExtensions_swrast
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/shy/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/shy/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
primus: fatal: failed to acquire direct rendering context for display thread
```

If I run steam using `optirun`, the steam itself works fine but when it comes to launching Dota, it gives me some other errors.
Launch options:

```
LD_PRELOAD=libpthread.so.0 libGL.so.1 __GL_THREADED_OPTIMIZATIONS=1 optirun %command%
```

Log itself:

```
Game update: AppID 570 "Dota 2", ProcID 10988, IP 0.0.0.0:0
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/shy/.steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
/bin/sh: 1: libGL.so.1: not found
Game removed: AppID 570 "Dota 2", ProcID 10988
```

I tried to manually copy libGL.so.1 from my `/usr/lib32/nvidia-343` to `~/steamlibs` and use it instead. Now Dota gives me a segfault.

```
Game update: AppID 570 "Dota 2", ProcID 12567, IP 0.0.0.0:0
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/shy/.steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
Game removed: AppID 570 "Dota 2", ProcID 12567
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same problem here. Using ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I'm having a similar "failed to acquire direct rendering context" problem, too; see [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/slackware-current-kernel-3-14-16-and-nvidia-optimus-4175514098/#post5224966).

Comment: Here's a Dec. 14, 2014, patch pertaining to the "failed to acquire direct rendering context" issue: http://pastebin.com/fJTtpHGU

Comment: Please mention your ubuntu version, driver version and graphics card
chipset when you ask questions like this Bumblebee is outdated, use nvidia-prime instead + an nvidia driver +
enable performance mode in nvidia-settings